# Jetpack Compose: When does a Coroutine-Scope leave the Composition?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines

From the official documentation: "rememberCoroutineScope is a composable function that returns a CoroutineScope bound to the point of the Composition where it's called. **The scope will be cancelled when the call leaves the Composition.**"

Please see here for the full text: [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects#remembercoroutinescope)

**What is meant by "leaving the Composition"?**

Can someone provide a concrete example? Currently can't imagine how the bold sentence is meant.

Comment: if your composable function is not visible anymore on the screen, that's called leaving the composition